# Row to Column Group by ID SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
id name  date
-------------------
1  Adam  2018-10-01
1  Adam  2018-08-01
2  Eve   2018-07-01
2  Eve   2018-05-01
```

I want it to become like this:

```
id  name  firstdate   lastdate
--------------------------------
1   Adam  2018-08-01  2018-10-01
2   Eve   2018-05-01  2018-07-01
```

I tried to use this query but it failed:

```
SELECT * FROM View_MySource
PIVOT (
    MIN(mydate)
    FOR id IN ([firstdate], [lastdate])
) piv
```

I am new to pivot, can someone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I might even avoid using `PIVOT` in this case:

```
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    MIN(date) AS firstdate,
    MAX(date) AS maxdate
FROM View_MySource
GROUP BY
    id,
    name;
```

Comment: thank you so much, im stuck in pivot before i read this, you help me alot

Answer (score 4):

This has actually nothing to do with pivoting data. All you want to do is get the minimum and maximum date per ID; a simple aggregation:

```
select id, name, min(date) as firstdate, max(date) as lastdate
from view_mysource
group by id, name
order by id;
```

Comment: thank you so much, im stuck in pivot before i read this, you help me alot